# How do i scrollRight in Jquery without Animate event?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

How do i **scrollRight** in **JQuery** without animate event.
For **scrollLeft**  ,we give like this

```
 $("body","html").scrollLeft();
```

for scrollRight is possible without animate event?

scrollRight is possible with scrollLeft event?

Comment: `$("body","html").scrollLeft('100');` apply with in a value its will be scroll right

Comment: Thanks prasad.it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("body","html").scrollLeft('100');` Apply with in a value its will be scroll right.Example as shown below

[For more Information](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("div").scrollLeft('200');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:130px;overflow:auto">
The longest word in the english dictionary is: pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.
</div><br>

<button>scroll right</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is the thing , i am expected..super